# what's the necessary condition to PSK-8 system have the same error probability of a QAM-8 system?

Tags: digital-communications, digital-modulation

I was solving a problem about digital modulations from my university exam that consider a QAM-8 system with adjacent signals coded by gray code, I know that  the error of this system is:

$$
P_{QAM-8} = 4.Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{3.\epsilon_{av}}{7.N_0}} \right)
$$

Don't my ask why, but the question asks to compare this error with a PSK-8 error probability and determine the necessary condition to this system have the same error probability of a QAM-8,

in this case regarding the adjacent points coded with gray code, we have:
$$
P_{PSK-8} = 2.Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{2.\epsilon_s}{N_0}}.sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) \right)
$$

OK, naturally when can conclude that
$$P_{PSK-8} = P_{QAM-8}$$,
and it's exactly where the problem is, second the solution model of my exam the arguments must be equal:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{2.\epsilon_s}{N_0}}.sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{3.\epsilon_{av}}{7.N_0}}
$$

But it doesn't make any sense, the integrated Gaussians distributions named by Q are multiplied by different factors. I don't have any guessing about it, or my solution model exam is wrong or there is something I don't know, could someone help me??

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. At the same noise power, these two modulation schemes have different error probability. We **cannot** just conclude \$P_{\text{PSK-8}} = P_{\text{QAM-8}}\$.

Comment: the question asks me what's the necessary condition to a PSK-8 and QAM-8 have the same performance in terms of error probability.

Comment: well, then you can't assume the same noise power for both! (by the way, it's not obvious to me how a 8-QAM looks like; I can think of at least constellations that I would call 8-QAM, though I've only seen one of them actual in applications, but its error probability is IIRC slightly more complicated)